# htaccess request rewritten to hidden subdir exposes subdir when trailing slash omitted

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-dir

There's a domain `example.com` which is an alias for the main domain.
My goal is to point `example.com` to the subdirectory `example.com/` of the main site.

This subdirectory has a child directory `test/`.

`.htaccess` is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ example.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

1. `https://example.com/test/` -> this works well, it shows `./example.com/test/index.html` without any redirects showing the URL as is.
2. `https://example.com/test` (no slash at the end) -> works as redirect to `https://example.com/example.com/test/`, but it changes the URL and adds the unnecessary dir path, WHY?

How to make it work as in #1 in both cases?

Comment: Try switching off content negociation. And check if there are any other rules implemented that handle the trailing slash pocily in your hosts. Those might interact withthe rule you posted here.

Comment: Nope, tried to leave just these stanzas for test, behaviour is the same, brain is still crushed ^^

Comment: So what is actually handling the trailing slash behavior in your setup?

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is that mod_dir appends the trailing slash to the *filesystem directory* (with a 301 redirect) after the internal rewrite has occurred (it's only then that Apache knows that it maps to a directory). This is necessary in order to be able to serve the `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.html`) from that directory (which is also handled by mod_dir).

To resolve this you need to manually append the trailing slash (if the request does ultimately map to a directory) *before* your internal rewrite in order to canonicalise the URL. Needless to say, the URL that includes the trailing slash is canonical and this is the URL you should be linking to internally.

For example:

```
# Append trailing slash if the file-path that the URL maps to is a directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example.com/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.+[^/])$ /example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite Requests to subdirectory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [L]
```

NB: The regex `^(.*)?$` is the same as simply `(.*)` and the `NC` flag was not required on that rule, since the regex is case-insensitive by its very nature.

*Aside:* The fact that your existing rewrite rule worked at all (and didn't result in a rewrite loop) is dependent on another `.htaccess` file existing in the `/example.com` subdirectory that also contains mod_rewrite directives. I have also used this assumption in the rule above. Otherwise, you would need additional checks to avoid a rewrite loop (and unnecessary filesystem checks).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to make sure all (browser) caches are cleared, since the earlier (erroneous) 301 redirect will have been cached by the browser.

---

*Aside:*

> There's a domain `example.com` which is an alias for the main domain.

Assuming you are on a shared hosting platform and depending on the type of hosting you have, you can often set the secondary domain as an "Add-on" domain (as opposed to an "Alias"), which effectively allows you to point the secondary domain directly at the subdirectory (with its own `DocumentRoot`) - so no need for manual URL rewriting in `.htaccess`.